# An inequality involving the normal distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be normal random variable with parameters $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 =1 $. Is it true that

$$ P( X > x ) \leq \frac{1}{x \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{ -x^2/2} \text{ for }x>0 \text{ ??}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{2\pi }P(X>x)=\int _x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt\leq \int _x^\infty \frac{t}{x}e^{-t^2/2}dt=\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x}$$

Comment: I dont think your inequality is always true

Comment: @WillieRosario but the inequality is true for every $t\in[x,\infty)$

Comment: why is this true for this condition ?